# Troubleshooting unexpected T_PUBLIC

Tags: php, parsing

I get this error..
***Parse error:syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC in C:\filename here on line 573***

On this line...

```
<i>public function findMaterialPostedThisMonth(){ </i>
```

The code...

```
public function findMaterialPostedThisMonth(){  
                    if (!empty($_GET['time'])) {
                            $month = date('n', $_GET['time']);
                            $year = date('Y', $_GET['time']);
                            if (!empty($_GET['pnc']) && $_GET['pnc'] == 'n') $month++;
                            if (!empty($_GET['pnc']) && $_GET['pnc'] == 'p') $month--;
                    } 
                    else {
                            $month = date('n');
                            $year = date('Y');
                    }

                    return $this->findAll(array(
                            'condition'=>'create_time > :time1 AND create_time < :time2
                                            AND t.status='.self::STATUS_PUBLISHED,
                            'params'=>array(':time1' => date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year)),
                                            ':time2' => date("Y-m-d", mktime(0,0,0,$month+1,1,$year)),
                                    ),
                            'order'=>'t.create_time DESC',
                    ));
            }
```

Comment: your not in a class, simply remove the word 'public'

Comment: I want to add a calendar of materials to the site is built on Yii Framework, and used in this manual    [link](http://loco.ru/materials/139-yii-calendar-materialov)

Comment: you would not get that error unless your function was outside of a class. so perhaps you put it in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `public` unless the function is being declared inside a class.